# How to enable Server Address Book in NamePicker Control of Extension Library in xPINC as its working fine in Browser

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-extlib

Is it possible to use the name picker of extlib in an xPINC app, to pick from the server side address book? Currently this control is working perfectly in browser and using server address book names.nsf, and while running as xpinc system is using local names.nsf by default but I want to use Server address book in xPINC.

I have gone through all configurations in location document, changed and updated information in dataProvider but failed to get desired results.

Please guide me the way forward. following is the page code.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="ibm.com/xsp/core" ; xmlns:xe="ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1"></xp:inputText>
    &#160;&#160;&#160;
    <xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="inputText1"
        dialogTitle="Please select Department Head">
        <xe:this.dataProvider>
            <xe:dominoNABNamePicker addressBookSel="all"
                groups="false" loaded="true" nameList="people" people="true"
                addressBookDb="lotustest9!!names.nsf">
            </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
        </xe:this.dataProvider>
    </xe:namePicker>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
 xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"><xp:inputText id="inputText1"></xp:inputText>
 &#160;&#160;&#160;
 <xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="inputText1"
  dialogTitle="Please select Department Head">
  <xe:this.dataProvider>
   <xe:dominoNABNamePicker addressBookSel="all" groups="false"
    loaded="true" nameList="people" people="true"
    addressBookDb="lotustest9!!names.nsf">
   </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
  </xe:this.dataProvider>
 </xe:namePicker> 
 <xp:br></xp:br>
 </xp:view>

Comment: Make sure "lotustest9" is your Domino server and your Notes Client knows about this server.